# How to add custom woocommerce admin field type

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i has already add one custom field type to woocommerce admin fields, and has worked 100%.

but this code is in the woocommerce plugin (woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php).

My problem now is how to exclude or hook or filter my custom woocommerce admin field type from woocoommerce plugin to my plugin. therefore, my custom field type still exists and worked when update woocommerce.

this is class-wc-admin-settings.php has customized

```
<?php
...
class WC_Admin_Settings {
...

public static function output_fields( $options ) {
...
switch ( $value['type'] ) {
    case 'productcategory' :

    $option_value = (array) self::get_option( $value['id'] );

    ?><tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $value['id'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value['title'] ); ?></label>
            <?php echo $tooltip_html; ?>
        </th>
        <td class="forminp forminp-<?php echo sanitize_title( $value['type'] ) ?>">
            <fieldset>

                <ul class="" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'hide_empty'=> 0,
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' 
                    );

                    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
                    $index = 0;
                    $count = count($all_categories);
                    $numItemsPerRow = ceil($count / 2);
                    $numItemsOffsetFix = $count % 2 == 1;

                    echo '<div class="columns" style="width:auto; display:inline-block; height:auto; float:left; padding:0; margin:0 25px 0 0;">';

                    foreach ($all_categories as $key => $val) {
                        if ($index > 0 and $index % $numItemsPerRow == 0) {
                            echo '</div><div class="columns">';
                            if ($numItemsOffsetFix) {
                                $numItemsPerRow--;
                                $numItemsOffsetFix = false;
                            }
                        }
                    //foreach ( $value['options'] as $key => $val ) {
                        ?>
                        <li style="">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" 
                                name="<?php echo esc_attr( $value['id'] ); ?>[]"
                                id="<?php echo esc_attr( $val->term_id )?>"
                                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $val->term_id )?>" 
                                <?php
                                    if ( in_array( $val->term_id,$option_value ) ) {
                                        echo ' checked="checked"';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                /> <?php echo $val->name; ?>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                        $index++;
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr><?php
 break;
...
} //end switch

...
} //end output_fields function

public static function save_fields( $options ) {
...
    switch ( $option['type'] ) {
    ...
        case 'productcategory':
        $value = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_clean', (array) $raw_value ) );
        break;
    ...
    }
...
} //end save_fields function

...
} //end class
?>
```

thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`do_action`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f7b2af7148d14a2317a0f156a18173c0c4c68fa7/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php#L612_) as the `default` case in the `switch` statement. Meaning, that if nothing has matched yet in the core code it will see if anything is attached to the action hook. Similarly, you can sanitize via the [`woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_$option_name` filter](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/f7b2af7148d14a2317a0f156a18173c0c4c68fa7/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-settings.php#L755)

Therefore, here's my best guess:

```
// handle output of new settings type
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_field_productcategory', 'output_productcategory_fields' );
function output_productcategory_fields( $value ) {

    $option_value = (array) WC_Admin_Settings::get_option( $value['id'] );

    ?><tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row" class="titledesc">
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $value['id'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $value['title'] ); ?></label>
            <?php echo $tooltip_html; ?>
        </th>
        <td class="forminp forminp-<?php echo sanitize_title( $value['type'] ) ?>">
            <fieldset>

                <ul class="" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'hide_empty'=> 0,
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' 
                    );

                    $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
                    $index = 0;
                    $count = count($all_categories);
                    $numItemsPerRow = ceil($count / 2);
                    $numItemsOffsetFix = $count % 2 == 1;

                    echo '<div class="columns" style="width:auto; display:inline-block; height:auto; float:left; padding:0; margin:0 25px 0 0;">';

                    foreach ($all_categories as $key => $val) {
                        if ($index > 0 and $index % $numItemsPerRow == 0) {
                            echo '</div><div class="columns">';
                            if ($numItemsOffsetFix) {
                                $numItemsPerRow--;
                                $numItemsOffsetFix = false;
                            }
                        }
                    //foreach ( $value['options'] as $key => $val ) {
                        ?>
                        <li style="">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" 
                                name="<?php echo esc_attr( $value['id'] ); ?>[]"
                                id="<?php echo esc_attr( $val->term_id )?>"
                                value="<?php echo esc_attr( $val->term_id )?>" 
                                <?php
                                    if ( in_array( $val->term_id,$option_value ) ) {
                                        echo ' checked="checked"';
                                    }
                                ?>
                                /> <?php echo $val->name; ?>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                        $index++;
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <?php echo $description; ?>
            </fieldset>
        </td>
    </tr><?php

}

// sanitize data for new settings type
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_productcategory', 'sanitize_productcategory_option', 10, 3 );
function sanitize_productcategory_option( $value, $option, $raw_value ){
    $value = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_clean', (array) $raw_value ) );
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: wow.. this worked 1000%..

but, i don't know why my code not work, i think because i don't use woocommerce admin settings class to option_value variable. like your code, on this line:

    $option_value = (array) WC_Admin_Settings::get_option( $value['id'] );


btw, thanks my viking, you saved my day

Comment: That's great! I didn't test it, so it was an educated guess. I'm not sure which code of yours you are referring to? Is there something not working?

Comment: i think my code not working bcause my head so tired.. over stack :) 
anyway, thanks helga

Comment: hi Helga, 

i have other trouble now, this field cannot save to our options table..

please help me

i has try many method, but still unluck (can't saved if all checkbox is empty)

my option name is "myoption"
my field name is "myfield"

  
    $options = get_option("myoption");
    if(isset($_POST['myfield'])){
    update_option( 'myoption',  $_REQUEST['myfield'] );
    }

Comment: Probably because `woocommerce_admin_settings_sanitize_option_productcategory` is incorrect. Please edit your question to add the code you are using the define the options for your plugin... and especially the `$this->id` of the class where you are initializing these settings.

Comment: i was check in table database, the option is saved succesfull.. but the page not reload. so i have to reload/refresh page as manually.